# Video controls like seek dragging video progress bar is not working in HTML?

Tags: html, django, web, video

Video control like seek 10 sec video progress bar dragging is not working in HTML:

```
<video controls width=100% height=100% preload="auto" preload="metadata" autoplay="autoplay" >
    <source src={{objs.video.url}} type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

> Note : I use Django

Answer (score -1, accepted):

install static-ranges and dj-static using pip

then go to wsgi.py

and do the following

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from dj_static import Cling, MediaCling
from static_ranges import Ranges

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'bharathwajan.settings')

application=Ranges(Cling(MediaCling(get_wsgi_application())))